# C++ reinterpret_cast - will this always work correctly?

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

I have written MyString and MyStringConst class. Now I need from time to time pass MyString as MyStringConst, hence overload cast operator. I have written this

```
MyString::operator const MyStringConst &() const
{
    return reinterpret_cast<const MyStringConst &>(*this);
}
```

MyString has this data

```
char * str;
int length;
volatile int hashCode;
int bufferSize;
```

MyStringConst has this data

```
const char * c_str;
int length;
volatile int hashCode;
```

Plus there are some methods, that in both strings can recalculate hashCode.

Is this code correctly written. I have tested it on MSVC 2013 and it is working correctly, but I have no idea if it can be used in production code, that can be compiled with different compiler.

Comment: if they're two totally different classes, you can't just reinterpret cast one to the other.  data may be misaligned and so on...  what's the point of MyStringConst.  Why not just use const MyString?

Comment: @thang MyString allocates a new string, MyStringConst not (just a wrapper around a pointer), but I need to compare them.

Comment: In practice, it will PROBABLY work in all compilers you'll ever encounter in real life. But in strict langauge-lawyer terms, definitely not guaranteed to work.

Comment: If ALL you need is a comparison, then you could write  a `compare` function that takes the four possible combinations [and that would just be a thin wrapper over a compare function that compares two `const char *` - possibly with the length (of the shorter or both) passed in too]

Comment: @MatsPetersson compare is inside class, I have no access to. It has method `bool IsSame(T & c)` where `T` is `MyStringConst`, because I have created member instance with that (`Foo<MyStringConst> collection;`)

Comment: Then redesign that! ;)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Well. I can add ctor to MyStringConst, that will take MyString and create a new instance... I will have some performance penalty hit, but it will be cleaner solution :-)

Comment: Doesn't sound like that bad a solution to me. If you are sure that nothing changes the `MyString` for the duration of the comparison [which would be bad if you cast it too], then you could just copy the pointer and length, which is probably not much overhead at all [especially if it's inlined, the compiler may be able to eliminate the extra copies altogether]

Comment: If I found this in production code as a replacement for `std::string` and `std::string const`, I'd certainly have a lot to talk about at the next code review...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common initial sequence of the data member is different and C++ makes no guarantee at all about the layout in this case, even if the types differ only by `const` qualification. Otherwise the guarantees for `union`s would effectively imply that the types need to have a common layout if they are standard-layout types (according to a note in 9.5 [class.union] paragraph 1).

In practice I would expect that the two types are laid out identical and that the `reinterpret_cast` works but there is no guarantee by the standard. Based on your comment `MyStringConst` merely holds a pointer to the string, i.e., instead of converting to references, I would just return a suitably constructed `MyStringConst` and avoid relying on undefined behavior:

```
MyString::operator MyStringConst() const {
    return MyStringConst(str, length);
}
```

The `MyString` object still has to live as long as the result from the conversion but this is no different to the case using `reinterpret_cast`.

BTW, the `volatile` on the `hashCode` is ill-advised: the only effect it will have is to slow down the program. I guess you are trying to use it to achieve synchronization between threads but in C++ `volatile` doesn't help with that at all: you get a data race when writing the member in one thread it is also accessed unsynchronized in another thread. You'd spell the member

```
std::atomic<int> hashCode;
```

instead.

Comment: Some nitpicking: In general, corresponding types **can** differ by const qualification and be part of the common initial sequence, according to [9.2p16]; they just need to be layout-compatible, and, according to [3.9p11], this includes types with different cv-qualifications. Here, however, the corresponding first members are *pointers to layout-compatible types*, and, to muddy the waters, the standard doesn't strictly call such pointers "layout-compatible".

Comment: It does, however, say something that should be equivalent, in [3.9.2p3]: *[...] Pointers to layout-compatible types shall have the same value representation and alignment requirements [...]*. I think this should make this case pretty well-specified, even though in a strict word-by-word interpretation of the standard the two types don't have a common initial sequence. I'd venture to guess that the *intent* of the standard is that they do.

Comment: Just found an additional indication: the footnote to [3.9.3p1]: *The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and non-static data members of unions.*

Comment: I've just realized that what I'm quoting has mostly been added as a result of [DR1719](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1719), which was only included in N4296, after C++14. Maybe a DR-to-the-DR would be useful :-), in order to make pointers to layout-compatible types be layout-compatible themselves?

Comment: @bogdan You can get fun cyclic dependencies that way. Consider: `struct A; struct B; struct A {B * pb;}; struct B {A * pa;};`. Are `A` and `B` layout-compatible?

Comment: @T.C. Good point. Clearly it has to be more restrictive. But I still think that examples like the one in the OP are already, essentially, layout-compatible, even though the wording doesn't include them. How about this: in addition to the criteria in [3.9p11], *two types P1 and P2 are layout compatible if they are similar (4.4)*? (Aliasing through such types is already allowed by [3.10p10.3].) What do you think?