# Is this use of reinterpret_cast on differently-qualified struct members safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing

<sub>I have looked at the following — related — questions, and none of them seem to address my exact issue: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7762929/), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10204032/), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28792554/).</sub>

I am writing a collection of which the elements (key-value pairs) are stored along with some bookkeeping information:

```
struct Element {
    Key key;
    Value value;
    int flags;
};

std::vector<Element> elements;
```

(For simplicity, suppose that both `Key` and `Value` are standard-layout types. The collection won't be used with any other types anyway.)

In order to support iterator-based access, I've written iterators that override `operator->` and `operator*` to return to the user a pointer and a reference, respectively, to the key-value pair. However, due to the nature of the collection, the user is never allowed to change the returned key. For this reason, I've declared a `KeyValuePair` structure:

```
struct KeyValuePair {
    const Key key;
    Value value;
};
```

And I've implemented `operator->` on the iterator like this:

```
struct iterator {
    size_t index;

    KeyValuePair *operator->() {
        return reinterpret_cast<KeyValuePair *>(&elements[index]);
    }
};
```

My question is: is this use of `reinterpret_cast` well-defined, or does it invoke undefined behavior? I have tried to interpret relevant parts of the standard and examined answers to questions about similar issues, however, I failed to draw a definitive conclusion from them, because…:

- the two struct types share some initial data members (namely, `key` and `value`) that only differ in `const`-qualification;
- the standard does not explicitly say that `T` and `cv T` are layout-compatible, but it doesn't state the converse either; furthermore, it mandates that they should have the same representation and alignment requirements;
- Two standard-layout class types share a common initial sequence if the first however many members have layout-compatible types;
- for union types containing members of class type that share a common initial sequence, it is permitted to examine the members of such initial sequence using either of the union members (9.2p18).
  – there's no similar explicit guarantee made about `reinterpret_cast`ed pointers-to-structs sharing a common initial sequence.
  – it is, however, guaranteed that a pointer-to-struct points to its initial member (9.2p19).

Using merely this information, I found it impossible to deduce whether the `Element` and `KeyValuePair` structs share a common initial sequence, or have anything other in common that would justify my `reinterpret_cast`.

As an aside, if you think using `reinterpret_cast` for this purpose is inappropriate, and I'm really facing an XY problem and therefore I should simply do something else to achieve my goal, let me know.

Comment: Are you asking for a [tag:language-lawyer] judgement? Does it work actually? `reinterpret_cast` is almost always the wrong approach, shouldn't a `const_cast` work well for what you're claiming?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, I'm asking for a language-lawyer judgement. **I cannot possibly tell whether it actually works** or it just "appears to be working" since I don't know whether it invokes undefined behavior. I don't know whether `const_cast` should work in this case, but let me try it – it's still not clear, however, whether `const_cast` compiling would mean that this is well-defined.

Comment: _"however, whether const_cast compiling would mean that this is well-defined."_ Of course, I think that's the purpose of it. Using a `reinterpret_cast` can't guarantee anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is: is this use of reinterpret_cast well-defined, or does
>   it invoke undefined behavior?

`reinterpret_cast` is the wrong approach here, you're simply violating strict aliasing. It is somewhat perplexing that `reinterpret_cast` and `union` diverge here, but the wording is very clear about this scenario.

You might be better off simply defining a union thusly:

```
union elem_t {
   Element e{}; KeyValuePair p;
   /* special member functions defined if necessary */
};
```

… and using that as your vector element type. Note that cv-qualification is ignored when determining layout-compability - [basic.types]/11:

> Two types *cv1* `T1` and *cv2* `T2` are layout-compatible types if
>   `T1` and `T2` are the same type, […]

Hence `Element` and `KeyValuePair` do indeed share a common initial sequence, and accessing the corresponding members of `p`, provided `e` is alive, is well-defined.

---

Another approach: Define

```
struct KeyValuePair {
    Key key;
    mutable Value value;
};

struct Element : KeyValuePair {
    int flags;
};
```

Now provide an iterator that simply wraps a `const_iterator` from the vector and upcasts the references/pointers to be exposed. `key` won't be modifiable, but `value` will be.

Comment: Thanks! It's actually not surprising to hear that `reinterpret_cast` is simply the wrong thing to do.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `struct Element { struct KeyValuePair pair; int flags}`.